# What is usage of "conflict" in composer.json and what should I do with it?

Tags: php, composer-php, yarnpkg, package.json, pipfile

I found the `composer.json & composer.lock`(php) has `conflict`  section (not to be confused with merge conflict ). The other similar files like `package.json/yarn.json` (nodejs) or `Pipfile` (python) and the corresponding **lock** files `package-lock.json/yarn.lock` or `Pipfile.lock`,  do not have such format even though all these lock files serve the same purpose (lock the dependence to the exact version) and implement in the similar way (at least looking from the surface)

So what is usage of it and what should I do with it ? I read the composer document https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#conflict but I still feel confused, e.g.

> Map of packages that conflict with this version of this package. They will not be allowed to be installed together with your package.

For example after running `composer install` I have a composer.lock saying

```
    {
        "name": "symfony/http-kernel",
        "version": "v4.4.20",
        ...
        "conflict": {
            "symfony/browser-kit": "<4.3",
            "symfony/config": "<3.4",
            "symfony/console": ">=5",
            "symfony/dependency-injection": "<4.3",
            "symfony/translation": "<4.2",
            "twig/twig": "<1.43|<2.13,>=2"
        },
    ...
```

It is easy to guess "symfony/console" 5.0 is conflicted with "symfony/http-kernel" 4.4.20 so `symfony/console 5.0` will not be installed.

Do I need to do anything with the conflict ? So far I feel like that as a package user (not the package developer) those info is just a FYI and I don't need to do anything. But then why bother to list them for me ? After all package.json and Pipefile don't have such information and I don't find the problem without it.

--- update ---

From the answer I got I realize I need to emphasize this: I understand **composer.lock** is for composer so I don't need to worry about it.

What I don't understand is the purpose putting it in **composer.json**, this file is for human users. So if it has a conflict section what should I do about it?

Comment: What makes you think that you need to do anything with the stuff written to `composer.lock`? If you are not familiar with that file, and you are not facing any specific problem, simply accept that it's there and don't open it ;)

Comment: Also, Composer handles all that conflict stuff for your. You don't need to do anything about it on your own, unless you face any problem running Composer

Comment: I don't and I also added an update to say I don't. It is the composer.json I feel confused.

Comment: So, what **exactly** is confusing for you? If you don't want to list anything in the `conflicts` section of your own `composer.json`, you don't need to. Just skip it

Comment: For example I want to know a practical use case of "conflict" section in my composer.json if I am not a package developer but a package user. Also I come from nodejs background so I feel odd to see it in composer.json.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I want to know a practical use case of "conflict" section in my composer.json if I am not a package developer but a package user.

When building an application, you are free to choose your dependencies way better than when you are building a reusable library like `symfony/http-kernel` which you've mentioned in your question.

Putting any other package constraint in the `conflict` section of such a package means: if you want to install the package in the current version, no other package version must be installed that is listed in the conflict section. From your example: `symfony/http-kernel` in v4.4.20 must not be installed if `symfony/browser-kit` is installed in any version `<4.3`.

In your own application, you have more freedom to use stricter constraints for the packages you use. You **could** require all packages with pretty strict version numbers, but this makes updates less comfortable. For example, this is a part of the `require` section in one of my current projects:

```
        "doctrine/annotations": "^1.0",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.2",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.0",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.7",
        "easycorp/easyadmin-bundle": "^3.1",
        "exercise/htmlpurifier-bundle": "^3.1",
        "knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle": "^1.8",
        "league/csv": "^9.6",
        "lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle": "^2.10",
        "nelmio/cors-bundle": "^2.1",
```

All these packages might install tons of other dependencies which I cannot control. But if I know that **any** version of the other dependencies causes trouble, I can list them in the `conflict` section of my application such that this version is not installed.

For example, in the past I've needed that for an update of `doctrine/migrations` where the configuration has changed. I wanted to be able to update all packages except this one, because I didn't want to bother with the configuration changes I had to apply to my application for a while.

Comment: So conflict is more for package developer but as a package user if I know a specific version of a package will cause the trouble I can list it in conflict section ?

Comment: Yes, that's how you could nail it down to one sentence. And unless you need it, simply ignore it

Comment: Now I think about it npm/package.json indeed seem to lack of methods to handle this!

Answer (score 7):

```
"conflict": {
    "symfony/console": ">=5",
```

this means that for some reason your package can't work with `symfony/console` version 5 and higher, so it will keep it below 5.

E.g. you can exclude some package faulty version:

```
"conflict": {
    "foo/bar": "1.420.69",
}
```

Comment: But I am just a user and that info is for "symfony/http-kernel". What should I do and what can I do with that info ?

Comment: Lock file is for composer, not for you, you do not care what's inside lock file. You can put this information inside `composer.json` - it's instructions for composer

Comment: I just feel this info is quite odd as I can from nodejs & python background.

Comment: No, it's not odd

Comment: Hi I update my question to make my question more clearer. I understand lock file is for composer.

Comment: @Qiulang Your update does not change my answer in any way: `conflict` is special way to tell composer that you do not want to update to specified version or version range.

Comment: OK now I feel that information is for the package developer. As a package user I don't need to worry about it. Right ?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post, but thought I'd add a point to what's already been said:

You may still benefit from a conflict section in composer.json if you know any of your code conflicts with any packages. It could be any reason from both your code and the package trying to do similar jobs and stepping on each other's toes or simply that a package is badly written and breaks your code.

In that case, you can add a conflict section in your composer.json to tell composer to never download that package (or some releases of it).

This would be useful if you work with other developers and someone else might try to require that package, or if you worry that composer may try to install it as a dependency of yet another package e.g. X is the package you don't want, but another package Y depends on X and you don't know. Without the conflict section, composer would download package X without you even knowing/noticing.

Comment: Now I wonder why only php community uses that.

Comment: @Quilang: Handling conflicts in dependency versions is not unique PHP dependencies, you have this in many similar tools. And as you asked for a practical use-case, this is one composer.json that makes use of it: https://github.com/Roave/SecurityAdvisories/blob/latest/composer.json - This keeps versions of packages out that have been flagged for defects securely running PHP in a stable manner. Just to give one very colorful example.